# Implemented a class for unweighted and weighted graphs JAVA

Tags: java, graph

I am preparing for technical interviews at the moment, and I have started to view my knowledge on graphs. I am using Java to implement the graphs from scratch.

So far I have covered weighted graphs and unweighted graphs. I would like to know if there is a way to combine both of these graphs types into one class?

I know the approach (if using adjacency lists) for unweighted graphs is to store an array of LinkedList with each of the vertices on the Graph class object itself. We can then add the vertices to this graph to create the graph, whereby each of the vertices in the graph is linked to other vertices on the LinkedList.

For the weighted graph approach (using adjacency lists), we can create a Edge class which holds the destination, source, and weight information for the vertices which the edge is connected to. We can then store this in a LinkedList on the Graph class object.

I was thinking maybe introducing an Enum field on the Graph class so that we can determine if the Graph is a Weighted Graph or a Non Weighted Graph. This would look like this.

```
private LinkedList<Edge> adjList[];
private GraphType graphType;
private int vertices;
```

Where GraphType is an Enum:

```
public enum GraphType {
    WEIGHTED,
    NON_WEIGHTED
}
```

How would this Graph class implementation look like?

Cheers!

Comment: It would look exactly the same as a weighted graph class? But you would be ignoring all of the weighted functionality/methods if the type was NON-WEIGHTED and just give the first shortest path found rather than the best weighted path. A better solution might be to have a base graph class (non-weighted) with the normal functionality, and have a weighted graph class that extends the base graph class and adds the additional functionality?

Comment: Ah yes, this is a good solution doing inheritance. I can't believe I missed this. Thanks a lot!